# What are the available GIS APIs out there?

Tags: api, gis

I'm looking APIs to get some geographical information. Particularly, I'm interested in GIS layers that depict some semantics like roads, vegetation, buildings. If there is an API to get the type of vegetation, it'd be awesome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you mean.  But if you are looking to download GIS data, I recommend using Quantum GIS (open source - http://qgis.org/).  Then use the OpenLayers or OpenStreetMap plugin to download data such as roads, buildings, and possibly vegetation.  It is going to depend on how much information exists on that area.